# If $\alpha$ $\in$ $(0,2)$ study the convergence of the sequence given with recurrence relation $X_{n+1}=\alpha X_{n}-(1-\alpha)X_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\alpha$ $\in$ $(0,2)$ study the convergence of the sequence given with recurrence relation $X_{n+1}=\alpha X_{n}-(1-\alpha)X_{n-1}$.

Find the limit of the sequence.

Can somebody help me with this problem?
I only studied sequences with recurrence relation give with firsts conditions. I don't know how to deal with these ones.
I would appreciate some help

Comment: Are there initial conditions?

Comment: No. That's why I don't know what to do

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I missed that bit in your question.

Comment: It's ok. Do you have any idea how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_n=Aa^n+Bb^n$ for some constants $A$ and $B$, where $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-\alpha x+(1-\alpha)=0$. The sequence is convergent if both $|a|\le 1$ and $|b|\le 1$.

When $\alpha^2-4(1-\alpha)<0$, i.e. when $0<\alpha<2\sqrt{2}-2$, the quadratic equation has unreal roots, $|a|=|b|$ and $|a||b|=|ab|=1-\alpha<1$. The sequence is convergent.

When $\alpha^2-4(1-\alpha)\ge0$, i.e. when $2\sqrt{2}-2\le \alpha<2$, the quadratic equation has real roots. Let $a\le b$ Then $\displaystyle a=\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha-4}}{2}=\frac{2(1-\alpha)}{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha-4}}$ and $\displaystyle b=\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha-4}}{2}$.

So, when $2\sqrt{2}-2\le \alpha\le 1$, $0\le a\le b$. We have to consider $|b|$ only.
\begin{align*}
|b|=\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4(\alpha-1)}}{2}\le \frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4(\alpha-\alpha)}}{2}=\alpha\le1
\end{align*}

The sequence is convergent.

If $1<\alpha<2$, then
\begin{align*}
|b|=\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4(\alpha-1)}}{2}\ge \frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2}}{2}=\alpha>1
\end{align*}
The sequence is divergent.

---

The sequence is convergent when $0<\alpha\le1$.

When $0<\alpha<1$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=0$.

When $\alpha=1$, $X_{n+1}=X_n$ and the seqeunce is a constant sequence.

---

As Youem pointed out in the comment, there is a special case that the sequence is convergent even when $1\le\alpha<2$.

If $1\le\alpha<2$, then
\begin{align*}
0\ge\frac{2(1-\alpha)}{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha-4}}\ge\frac{2(1-\alpha)}{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha-4\alpha}}=\frac{1}{\alpha}-1\ge-1
\end{align*}

and hence $|a|\le1$.

$X_n=Aa^n+Bb^n$ is convergent (when $1<\alpha<2$) if $B=0$, i.e. $X_n=Aa^n$

So, when  $1\le\alpha<2$, The sequence is convergent to $0$ when $\displaystyle X_2=\left(\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha-4}}{2}\right)X_1$.

Comment: For $\alpha > 1$ can we just say that the product is larger than $1$ ? One of the roots diverges ?

Comment: In addition we have to make sure that $A$ and $B$ are non zero to claim that the sequence diverges ?

Comment: @Youem The product of roots is $1-\alpha$ and cannot be larger than $1$. I agree with your comment on the value $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: But I want to say the sum is equal to $\alpha $ so one of them must have a real part larger than 1 ?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the computation of roots

Comment: @Youem When the sum of roots is between $1$ and $2$, we still may have two roots both less than $1$.

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$1)$ See that $X_n=0$ is a solution.

$2)$ Use the standard approach: $X_n=\lambda^n$ and see that:

$$\lambda^2-\alpha\lambda+1-\alpha=0$$
$$\lambda=\frac{\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\alpha-4}}{2}$$

analyse the last expression.

Can you finish?

Comment: Can we take $\alpha=0$? 0 is not in (0,2)

Comment: @J.Dane you are right

Comment: @J.Dane better now?

Comment: Yes. I'll see where I can go from there

Comment: I think I need a little more help @Arnaldo